# When booking a train when the clock is set back by one hour due to the daylight saving time, how can I know when the train is scheduled to depart?

Tags: trains, timezones, schedule-change

E.g., in the US, PT time zone, on Sunday, November 6, 2022, 2:00:00 am PT, the clock was reset to Sunday, November 6, 2022, 1:00:00 am PT. If I book a train ticket scheduled to depart on November 6, 2022, 1:30:00 am PT, how can I know whether the train is scheduled to depart before the clock is reset?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because I don't think it's useful to have the exact same question that only changes the mode of transportation.

Comment: @GregHewgill but the answers differ, and the question may too broad.

Comment: I don't think they do - the general answer is either "ask the service provider" or "there are no scheduled services at that time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Europe, the train operators usually do as follows:

- On e.g. suburban lines with frequent departures, there will be extra departures during the extra hour. A train scheduled to depart 2:30 will run *both* 2:30 CEST *and* 2:30 CET. (In Europe, the clocks are set back from 3:00 to 2:00.)
- Long distance trains will wait for one hour at the first station they reach after 2:00 CEST, so that all departures after 2:00 are following winter time. If they don't wait, all departures after 3:00 would anyway be one hour early.

There may of course be strange exceptions particularly for trains travelling between areas where DST is used and where DST is not used. At least in Europe, AFAIK, all countries using DST switch back and forth at the same date. In other parts of the world, that is not always so and that will of course also lead to confusing situations.

These basic rules sound to me the easiest way to prevent anyone from missing their train, so I would assume that very similar approaches are used elsewhere in the world as well. After all, humans have lived with complicated and cluttered time zones for several hundred years, so even if we are still not willing to simplify everything a lot, we do at least have more than enough experience on how to make things work as smoothly as possible.

Comment: Several hundred years of complicated and cluttered time zones? :-) That's obviously not correct. Time zones have been invented and put into use in the final decades of the 19th century and haven't changed much since then. Throughout the history (until the advent of railways), humankind has used only local solar time.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Even if countries didn't switch to universal time zones based on full-hour GMT offsets until roughly 1850-1925, time was of course standardized before that as well and usually each city or smaller districts operated with their own time zone. Even if Berlin was at GMT+0:53:28 until Apr 1st 1893 and Paris at GMT+0:09:21 until March 11th 1911, these were also time zones.

Comment: I would argue that if each municipality sets its own local time based on local solar noon, it can't be called a time zone. If a bigger area such as Bavaria or Pennsylvania (not just one city) has one common time (weird GMT offset is not a problem), that is already a time zone. But such common times didn't exist before the 1850s, so it can't be "several hundred years of complicated and cluttered time zones".

Comment: @Johnnyjanko You may of course define time zones however you like, but that is not how the term is used elsewhere in the world. The size of the area is not relevant to define if we are talking about a time zone or not. Even now, time zones can be very small. For example Australian central western standard time is only 'used by some roadhouses along the Eyre Highway in Western Australia and South Australia'. In Antarctica, time zones often de facto only cover a single research station.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "A time zone is an area which observes a uniform standard time for legal, commercial and social purposes." You're right, it doesn't have to be big. But using a simple local solar time is not a time zone. Houses along the Eyre Highway don't have the same solar time. 200 years ago, each of them would use a different local time. Research stations in Antarctica use zonal time because it's convenient, not because it always matches the local solar time (that's what makes it a zonal time). https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/antarctica

Comment: According to your definition, any local time can be considered a time zone. That would mean time zones have existed since the beginning of human timekeeping, e.g. also in Antiquity. And that's definitely not the mainstream, accepted definition.